# Saving polylines to firebase in Kotlin?

Tags: firebase, google-maps, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, google-polyline

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment?
    mapFragment?.getMapAsync(this)
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "PotentialBehaviorOverride")
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
    map = googleMap!!
    map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this)
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this)
    map.uiSettings.apply {
        isZoomControlsEnabled = false
        isZoomGesturesEnabled = false
        isRotateGesturesEnabled = false
        isTiltGesturesEnabled = false
        isCompassEnabled = false
        isScrollGesturesEnabled = false
    }
    observeTrackerService()
}

private fun observeTrackerService() {
    TrackerService.locationList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        if (it != null) {
            locationList = it
            if (locationList.size > 1) {
                binding.stopButton.enable()
            }
            drawPolyline()
            followPolyline()
        }
    })
    TrackerService.started.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        started.value = it
    })
    TrackerService.startTime.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        startTime = it
    })
    TrackerService.stopTime.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        stopTime = it
        if (stopTime != 0L) {
            showBiggerPicture()
            displayResults()
        }
    })
}

private fun drawPolyline() {
    val polyline = map.addPolyline(
            PolylineOptions().apply {
                width(10f)
                color(Color.BLUE)
                jointType(JointType.ROUND)
                startCap(ButtCap())
                endCap(ButtCap())
                addAll(locationList)
            }
    )
    polylineList.add(polyline)
}

private fun followPolyline() {
    if (locationList.isNotEmpty()) {
        map.animateCamera(
                (CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(
                        setCameraPosition(
                                locationList.last()
                        )
                )), 1000, null)
    }
}






}

private fun showBiggerPicture() {
    val bounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()
    for (location in locationList) {
        bounds.include(location)
    }
    map.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                    bounds.build(), 100
            ), 2000, null
    )
    addMarker(locationList.first())
    addMarker(locationList.last())
}

private fun addMarker(position: LatLng){
    val marker = map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(position))
    markerList.add(marker)
}

private fun displayResults() {
    val result = Result(
            calculateTheDistance(locationList),
            calculateElapsedTime(startTime, stopTime)
    )



    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(2500)
        val directions = MapsFragmentDirections.actionMapsFragmentToResultFragment(result)
       findNavController().navigate(directions)
        binding.startButton.apply {
            hide()
            enable()
        }
        binding.stopButton.hide()
        binding.resetButton.show()
    

} `
```

I would like to send the polylines to Firestore. How to send the polylines in code to Firestore? Can anyone help? My code has a map fragment with buttons. This is a distance tracking app. The app plots the distance using polylines. How to convert polylines to arrays. Here I am doing a location tracking app. I want to convert the polylines to arrays so that I could save it cloud.

Comment: Polylines are just a list of lat/lng pairs, so you could just store them as a list of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation, a [Polyline](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline) is **not** a [Firestore supported data-type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). So there is no way you can add such an object to Firestore.

**What's a polyline?**

It's basically a list of points. So what you can do instead is to add all these points to Firestore. You can add them as simple as latitude and longitude or as [GeoPoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/GeoPoint) objects. If you have additional details for the locations, you can add them as documents in a collection, otherwise, you can store them in an array within a document.

To read them, simply create a reference to the document, loop through the array, create a new [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) object of each location, and add all of them to the polyline.

Comment: But how to convert this polyline into an array? Can you type the codes

Comment: There is no way to convert a polyline into an array. You should get the points that compose the polyline, one by one, and add them into an array. For that, you should start with the official documentation regarding [adding data to Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) and if you have hard times implementing something, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.